# Podcast client with scheduler?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, podcast

Can anyone suggest a Windows podcast client that includes a scheduler that restricts the hours during which podcasts will be downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a client with a scheduler, but gpodder has a command line version (gpo) that can be run with the Windows Task Scheduler (or cron on *nix systems). For the energy conscious, [Wake On Standby](https://dennisbabkin.com/wosb/) can be used to wake a Windows computer from sleep or even hibernate (assuming your bios supports it - pretty common in anything less than about 10 years old).

As far as I can tell, gpo will accept only a single command on the command line, so you'll need to write a script/batch file with the update and download commands. Redirecting input from a file doesn't seem to work.